# getattr access third argument even when condition not met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get value of an attribute of a class in a list only if attribute exist. If attribute does not exist I want it to get something else (I know it's inner list, and want to get item's attribute inside that inner list).

Example in the code below, which can be run and debugged:

```
class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.block_name = name


blocks_list = [Block("d"), Block("d"), Block("d")]
blocks = [Block("a"), Block("b"), blocks_list, Block("c")]

# this is ok
block_num = 2
name = getattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name', blocks[block_num][0].block_name)

# this is raises exception
block_num = 0
name = getattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name', blocks[block_num][0].block_name)
```

exception:

> name = getattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name',
>   blocks[block_num][0].block_name) TypeError: 'Block' object does not
>   support indexing

I dont understand why getattr raise exception on third argumnet when it's not suppose to.

My final goal is to et the name of all items, in the list or the inner list.

Thanks.

Comment: When `block_num` is 2, `blocks[block_num]` is a list. So `blocks[block_num][0].block_name` works because you're indexing a list. In the second example, the `Block` at `block_num` (0) is not a list, so you cannot index it like a list. You're probably getting an `AttributeError: Block has no attr "__getitem__"` because you're trying to index it like a list.

Comment: Thanks but that exactly my question, when block_num is 0, the function "getattr" suppose to return the second argument (the value of the existed attribute), but for some reason it also check the third argument. The third argument is not relevant in this case, because the attribute does exist.

Comment: What's the output you are expecting in this case @Izik ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first case works since when `block_num = 2`, `blocks[2][0]` is `<__main__.Block at 0x....>` which is an object, since `blocks[2]` is a list

In the first case, you have `getattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name', blocks[block_num][0].block_name)` for `block_num = 2` , `blocks[block_num]` is a list, and that list won't contain `block_name`, so the default value `blocks[block_num][0].block_name` is returned

In the second case, for `block_num=0`, the default gets evaluated when you call the function, but that ends up throwing `TypeError: 'Block' object is not subscriptable`, since`blocks[0]` is an object `<__main__.Block at 0x....>`, and you cannot index an object

To be consistent, one suggestion might be to do `blocks_list[block_num].block_name` instead

The updated code then might look like

```
class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.block_name = name


blocks_list = [Block("d"), Block("d"), Block("d")]
blocks = [Block("a"), Block("b"), blocks_list, Block("c")]

block_num = 2
name = getattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name', blocks_list[block_num].block_name)
print(name)

block_num = 0
name = getattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name', blocks_list[block_num].block_name)
print(name)
```

Which gives you

```
d
a
```

Comment: Unfortunately, change of the objects themselves are not allowed, only to get their data. But I got the acceptable answer below.

Comment: Hi @Izik I have updated my answer to ensure that the objects are not changed, can you take a look and see if it makes sense ?

Comment: Thanks @Devesh Kumar Singh. it works great and saves me the use of "if else"

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand why, in your second example, the third argument is raising an error - it's because `blocks[0]` is not a list, and so you can't index into it. I also think that you expect there not to be an error, because the third argument should only be evaluated if `blocks[0]` doesn't have an attribute `'block_name'` (since the third argument of `getattr()` is the default).

Unfortunately, it doesn't work like that. The third argument that you're giving `getattr()` (that is, `blocks[block_num][0]`) is evaluated when you *call* the function, not when it's *executed*.

There is a workaround to this, though: the ternary operator, which is able to do the same thing as `getattr()` (returns one property if it exists, and a default if it doesn't) but *does* evaluate the other arguments at execute-time rather than at call-time:

```
name = blocks[block_num].block_name if hasattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name') else blocks[block_num][0].block_name
```

In your call to `getattr()`, the three arguments are all evaluated at the same time, before the function is executed. In this expression I've presented, they instead get evaluated in the following order:

1. `if hasattr(blocks[block_num], 'block_name')`
2. `blocks[block_num].block_name` (if 1 is true)
3. `blocks[block_num][0].block_name` (if 1 is false)

which should solve your problem.